# Is it possible to delete a service acocunt token volume projection?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm projecting a token into a pod in order to use this token to authenticate into an external system. I do not fully trust the code that can potentially run into this pod, so I would like to use the token projection to perform the authentication and then remove the projected token so that the code that will run at a later time cannot use it.

When deleting the projected token I receive an answer that the filesystem is read only:

```
rm: can't remove '/var/run/secrets/tokens/..data': Read-only file system
rm: can't remove '/var/run/secrets/tokens/vault-token': Read-only file system
rm: can't remove '/var/run/secrets/tokens/..2019_12_06_09_50_26.580875372/vault-token': Read-only file system
```

When mounting the file system I specified that I want to mount it read write (I use a PodPreset to inject the projected folder into pods):

```
apiVersion: settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: PodPreset
metadata:
  name: pod-preset
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      my-pod: job
  env:
  volumeMounts:
  - name: token-mounter
    mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
    readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: token-mounter
    projected:
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          path: vault-token
          expirationSeconds: 7200
          audience: vault
```

Is there any way to make the projected file system writable or, in general, to remove the projected token?

Comment: Hi, what platform do you use? Also which version of Kubernetes?

Comment: I'm using microk8s with kubernetes 1.16.3

Answer (score 1):

No, as it says it uses a read only ramdisk so you can’t change things. I’m not 100% sure this is possible but you could try using an initContainer to copy the token to a r/w ramdisk volume and then skip mounting the token volume in the main container entirely.